# Alter value in pandas dataframe based on corresponding value in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes.

1. The first (df1) has two columns: 'Country' (string) and 'Population' (int). Each row consists of a different country and its corresponding population (~200 rows).
2. The second (df2) also has two columns: 'Country' (string) and 'Value' (int). Each country appears a variable number of times in random order with a corresponding value (thousands of rows).

I want to divide each value in df2['Value'] by the corresponding population of that row's country.

My attempt: (Assume there's a list called 'countries' containing all countries in these dataframes

```
for country in countries:
  val = df2.loc[df2['Country'] == country]['Values'] # All values corresponding to country
  pop = df1.loc[df1['Country'] == country]['Population'] # Population corresponding to country
  df2.loc[df2['Country'] == country]['Values'] = val / pop
```

Is there a better way to do this? Perhaps a solution that doesn't involve a for-loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `merge` for that:

```
df3 = df2.merge(df1, on='Country') # maybe you want to use how='left'
df3['Div'] = df3['Values'] / df3['Population']
```

You can read more about merge [in the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
# Assuming that there are the same countries in both df    
df3 = pd.merge(df2, df1, how = 'inner' on='Country')
df3["Values2"] = df3["Values"] / df3["Population"]
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative implementation would be to join the two tables before applying the division operator. Something on the line of:

```
df2 = df2.join(df1,on='Country',how='left')
df2['Values'] = df2['Values'] / df2['Population']
```